# Applications used for game design project tracking?

Tags: project-management, asset-management

I have been using a ton of different software to manage my game designs, and at times it is easy to loose track of something important.

I was wondering if there is anything that is able to facilitate the job; and that is a single application that can be used as hub, to centralize other applications for different purposes.

For example, this is what I have been doing for the past 12 years

- write on paper the idea, make some sketch of what you want the game to be
- in word create a document with bullet points about the game design
- in PS start to create sketches for look and feel of the game
- GIT to start to setup the code repository for the prototype
- Unity for the game prototype
- blender for the 3d models and animations
- microsoft projects to hold all the data together; in conjunction with trello

This is just a small part of the tools used; and it gets out of control pretty easy. I just wish there was a solution that would have designers to work in one environment, with the ability to open other applications if installed, so you can manage easily the various milestones and deadlines, assets, development and everything related to a game design project.

As writer I used to have a nice application that would help me to write stories, characters and scenes. That was very helpful to create cutscenes, dialogues and overall character sheet; including the ability to add 2d files and even 3d files; and I just wish there is something similar dedicated to game design; but I doubt it exist.

Is there any software that include multiple features that can help with design and tracking of the overall project (or if not a single one, a combination of applications)?

Where possible I would like to avoid apps that require me to buy a subscription or work via web on remote server. Due to security reasons and NDA,I would rather have all in local.

As OS I don't mind. I use Unity on both Win and OSX, and for the coding I have visual studio on both; so either OS is fine. As far as price; anything below 150 USD is reasonable I think.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to ask a question, showing what I use so I can get suggestions about how to cut on the list of tools used. Beside the dev tools, I am looking at something that is able to keep track of my project, assets and facilitate handling of the dates and milestones. Sadly the issue with existing tools is that I cannot use regular project management tools because they are limited only to workflow and not to asset and process managements too.

Comment: Don't forget MindMaps too :-)